# trying to pass variables adds extra characters

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables

Ive seen others address this several years back but they didnt seem to give a working answer.

When I try to pass these two commands in a batch file (they work when done by hand) :

```
nltest /dsgetsite>c:\windows\temp\site.txt 
set /p CurrentADSite<c:\windows\temp\site.txt
```

but when I attempt to issue the commands via a batch file I get this:

```
C:\working>nltest /dsgetsite  1>c:\windows\temp\site.txt

C:\working>set /p CurrentADSite  0<c:\windows\temp\site.txt
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

How on earth do I actually get this to work? Is there an easier way to pass the dsgetsite results straight into a variable?

Comment: This is a [su] question, not a [so] question.

Comment: Lasse, because batch files, shell scripts and other automation languages are not programming? I disagree.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for /f` to avoid the temp file (also you [usually] can't write to the Windows directory so that will blow up anyway):

```
for /f %%x in ('nltest /dsgetsite') do if not defined CurrentADSite set CurrentADSite=%%x
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://ss64.com/nt/set.html you may have missed out an =
"To place the first line of a file into a variable:
`Set /P _MyVar=<MyFilename.txt` "

If all else fails you could always fall back on:

```
:: start the temp batch with start of set command
echo set CurrentADSite=>c:\windows\temp\site.bat
:: add to the temp bat : the variable assignment
nltest /dsgetsite>>c:\windows\temp\site.bat
:: run the temp batch and return here
call c:\windows\temp\site.bat
```

Comment: Two problems: first Isnt this backward? shouldnt I set the site AFTER I populate the bat? 
Second, >> appends. wouldnt that cause the bat file to get bigger and bigger each time it ran as it appends the results of each subsequent run?

Comment: yeah, doesnt work. the bat file created is not coherent. it creates the actual variable on second line:

Comment: Sorry if the batch file ends up on 2 lines, that's beyond my control! I've edited my answer with something hopeful, hopefully :)  ... as for my fallback approach, the set happens second when the call is issued, the first echo just places a command in the batch text file but isn't executed until it's called. Second question : the echo clears the batch file back to a new file each time the 3 command are run, only the second write to the batch file does an append. HTH

Comment: You would have to use `>site.cmd <nul set /p X=set CurrentADSite=` instead because that's the only way to not get the trailing line break.

Comment: I'm confused.. can you write that line in full please, Joey. Many thanks